# Fixed header overlap

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a fixed header for a site I am making and the content is layered beneath the header. I want to have the content be drawn in under the header without he user having to scroll up. If at all possible I would like the user no not see any whitespace above the content.

Here is what I made so far http://jsfiddle.net/5QWZW/.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Elemental Fury</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" name="discription" content="Best game evar!!">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
        <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <nav>
                <table class="navTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="navItem"><a href="#Fire"><img class="navImage" src="Images/Fire.jpg" alt="Fire"></a></td>
                        <td align="center" class="navItem"><a href="#Air"><img class="navImage" src="Images/Air.jpg" alt="Air"></a></td>
                        <td align="center" class="navItem"><a href="#Earth"><img class="navImage" src="Images/Earth.jpg" alt="Earth"></a></td>
                        <td align="center" class="navItem"><a href="#Water"><img class="navImage" src="Images/Water.jpg" alt="Water"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </nav>
            <section>
                <h1 class="title">Fancy logo</h1>
                <div id="Fire" class="Page">
                    <h1>Fire</h1>
                    <img src="Images/archer%20fire.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/mage%20fire.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/soldier%20fire.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div id="Water" class="Page">
                    <h1>Water</h1>
                    <img src="Images/archer%20water.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/mage%20water.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/soldier%20water.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div id="Air" class="Page">
                    <h1>Air</h1>
                    <img src="Images/archer%20air.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/mage%20air.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/soldier%20air.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div id="Earth" class="Page">
                    <h1>Earth</h1>
                    <img src="Images/archer%20earth.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/mage%20earth.jpg"/>
                    <img src="Images/soldier%20earth.jpg"/>
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <a href="#Rules">Rules</a>
            </footer>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the css

```
    nav{
    height: 106px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 5px #d0d0d0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}
.navItem{
    width: 2%;
}
.navImage{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.navImage:hover{
    box-shadow: 10px 5px 5px #888888;
}
.Page{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
}
section{
    margin-top: 400px;
}
.Page:target{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
```

The images I have saved locally so I had to substitute with line breaks. It only becomes a problem when one clicks on one of the navigation links on the top of the page.

Comment: Works for me, also. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Add padding equal to the height of the header to each of the anchored divs.

For your example:

```
.Page { padding-top:106px; }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pHV58/)